# Need to find all invalid dom elements using knockout-validation

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, knockout-validation

I am using knockout-validation for validation.
I need to find all the observable variables which are invalid.

How can I find that?

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var invalidObservables = {};
for ( var prop in viewModel ) {
    if ( viewModel.hasOwnProperty( prop ) && ko.isObservable( viewModel[ prop ] ) ) {
        if ( viewModel[ prop ].hasOwnProperty( 'isValid' ) && !viewModel[ prop ].isValid() ) {
            invalidObservables[ prop ] = viewModel[ prop ];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this will give only error messages but I need actual binding observable, it would be better if HTLM control..

Comment: Ah, right, I've updated my answer to give you an object with the invalid observables.